# Linq Group By With Having

Tags: .net, linq

Here is my example:

```
class test{
    public DateTime dt;
    public double value;
    public int id;
}
```

i have:

```
IEnumerable<Test> TestList;
```

I want select rows from it, with group by id, with max(dt).

my query:

```
var q = from p in TestList
        group p by p.id
        into g
        select new { id = g.Key, dt = g.Max(w => w.dt) });
```

In result i have anonyoumus class with {id_param,dt}, but i want to have field "value" too, like {id,dt,value},how can i do it?

Comment: Which value do you want to return for each group? One that belongs to the max datetime? Any of them? Something else?

Comment: which belongs to max datetime, yes!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to group by all fields that are not aggregated. So value needs to be summed up or grouped by.

Try:

```
        var result = TestList
            .GroupBy(t => t.id)
            .Select(g => new { id = g.Key, g.OrderByDescending(c => c.dt).First().dt, g.OrderByDescending(c => c.dt).First().value });
```

Comment: i dont want to aggregate value, i need it as it is. maybe i need to use join?

Comment: well, if you are grouping by ID, that tells me there are more than one item with the same id (smells fishy), and if there are more than one, than you either have to aggregate the values or group by value as well.

Comment: lol, beacuse of many datetimes there are same ids, but what i want, is to select distinct ids, with max time, with their real values

Comment: in tsql i could do it by join, but in linq i dont know how to use join for this problem

Comment: I've added a suggestion in the reply

Comment: Suggestion: add a `let` so you only need to do the `OrderBy` once.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments and the question, you want: for each distinct id, the instance with the maximum `dt`.

I would add a help method: `MaxBy` which allows a whole object to be selected based on the value of a function<sup>1</sup>:

```
public static T MaxBy<T,TValue>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T,TValue> projector)
                                where TValue : IComparable<TValue> {
  T found = default(T);
  TValue max = default(TValue);
  foreach (T t in input) {
    TValue p = projector(t);
    if (max.CompareTo(p) > 0) {
      found = t;
      max = p;
    }
  }
  return found;
}
```

And then the query becomes:

```
var q = from p in TestList
        group p by p.id into g
        select g.MaxBy(w => w.dt);
```

**NB.** this implementation of `MaxBy` will only work for objects where the value of the member being compared is greater than its type's default value (e.g. for `int`: greater than zero). A better implementation of `MaxBy` would use the enumerator manually and initialise both `found` and `max` variables directly from the first element of the input.

---

<sup>1</sup> if you are using The Reactive Extensions (Rx) this is included in the `System.Interactive` assembly.

Comment: and where i have to add that method? sry for such questions

Comment: @eba: Corrected missing `)`. Add this to a static class in the assembly.

Comment: so, the way of danijels, seems to be easier